# Export the Pdf using the selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

In my code, I am trying to click on the View Application button containing the pdf. But it is unable to click and export the View Application PDF.
I want the View Application PDF should be exported automatically through selenium webdriver in python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 
   20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search- 
   pro-details']//a[contains(.,'Search Project Details')]"))).click()
Registered_Project_radio= WebDriverWait(driver, 
   10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"Promoter")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Registered_Project_radio)
Application = driver.find_element_by_id("CertiNo")
Application.send_keys("P50500000005")
Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 
   10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btnSearch")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Search)
View = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in 
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") if
       item.get_attribute('href') is not None]

View = View[0]
request = urllib.request.Request(View)
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
    "//a[@class='btn btn-md btn-success' and @id='btnShow_2017']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",btn)
```

Comment: Please Assist for the above issue not able to export the pdf.

Comment: Your code seems to work, it shows the pdf view in chrome. Are you expecting to view the pdf or download? Did you face any errors?